# What does “{} \;” mean in find (in Linux)?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

Sometimes I see a command like

```
find . -name * -exec ls -a {} \;
```

I was asked to execute this.

What does `{} \;` mean here?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85709/what-do-these-symbols-in-some-linux-terminal-commands-mean) question is similar, does it help you?

Comment: Please mention which operating system you are using. There are `find` commands for Unix, Linux, OSX, Windows and probably everything else. That looks like *nix but I can't be sure.

Comment: Yes i found the good answers here http://askubuntu.com/questions/85709/what-do-these-symbols-in-some-linux-terminal-commands-mean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\;` is a `;` fed to the program (find) by the `\` escape preventing it from be handled by the shell (normally would separate commands).  The `-exec` argument interprets everything as a command up to that inserted `;` that ends the `-exec` stuff.  Within the `-exec` stuff an argument of `{}` means "insert the file name here".  So if the files were "foo" and "bar" it would execute "ls -a foo" then "ls -a bar".  So all that meaning only means that because `-exec` is there.

The `-name *` part of it might have been meant with `*` in quotes.  If it is not in quotes it will do very unpredictable things because all the file names will be inserted in place of the `*` you have, and those names might do bad stuff to this command.  Leave `-name *` out for a safer run of this command (but I don't know your intentions to understand why that was in there).

Comment: For the find command with the `-name *` argument,  *If you aren't sure if you need quotes around your `*`, then you should add double, or single quotes*.  So it should be `-name "*"`.  To make it easier to see what happens when you don't use quotes type this command: `set +x; find . -name * -print` and you'll see that what is actually passed to the find command is `find . -name file1 file2 file3 file4 -print` (if you had `file1, file2,  file3, and file4`) in your current directory.